# Presenting two View Controllers at once in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller, viewdidappear

In my project, I am presenting a View Controller (firePromo()) in viewDidAppear based on certain criteria within the App itself. I've just finished integrating another View Controller (firePromo2()) that is to be presented in viewDidAppear.

Both View Controllers function and display as intended... But there is a chance that both View Controllers will be triggered at the same time on a launch. Granted - probability is low, but there's still a chance.

My code is below:

```
func firePromo() {
    hasShownPromo = true
    // ...
    self.present(promoView, animated: true, completion:nil)
}

func firePromo2() {
    hasShownPromo2 = true
    // ...
    self.present(promoView2, animated: true, completion:nil)
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if hasShownPromo == false {
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasWatchedPromo") {
            let promoLaunchCounterFromKey = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "launchCountForPromoKey")                
            if promoLaunchCounterFromKey == 4 || promoLaunchCounterFromKey == 9 || promoLaunchCounterFromKey == 14 {
                firePromo()
            }
        }
    }

    if hasShownPromo2 == false {
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasWatchedPromo2") {                
            let promoLaunchCounterFromKey2 = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "launchCountForPromoKey2")
            if (promoLaunchCounterFromKey2 % 5) == 0 {
                firePromo2()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I realize that with the above code, it *appears* that firePromo() & firePromo2() won't evaluate at the same time (5 != divisible by 4 / 9 / 14) - however, there's extra logic involved with promo2 in appDelegate. So there is a chance both will evaluate.

**What is the best way to safely handle the presentation of these two View Controllers in the event that both WILL fire at the same time?**

Comment: Do an else/if test instead of to consecutive if?

Comment: @Larme - So if I do "else if hasShownPromo2 == false" - in the event that both fire at the same time, just firePromo() will evaluate, and not firePromo2(), correct?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. If both controllers should be displayed, how do you want them to appear? E.g. you could present a navigation controller with both promo VCs as child controllers; or you could present the first controller and once it's closed present the second.

Comment: @dr_barto - If both criteria are met, and both have to fire at the same time, showing just 1 is fine with me! So long as the next time criteria is met, the *other* fires. - The thing with these VC's is once the user taps the call to action button on each, it sets NSUserDefaults to not show again. So again, the likelyhood of both having to show at the same time is rare, but I need to account for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Early return method.

```
if promoLaunchCounterFromKey == 4 || promoLaunchCounterFromKey == 9 || promoLaunchCounterFromKey == 14 {
    firePromo()
    return
}
```

Add a return after `firePromo2()` too. Just a suggestion though; segregate all the fire promo code into a distinct method and call the method from `viewDidAppear:`. That way, when the method returns early, you are not blocking `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Check out the reply I posted above directed to @dr_barto.

Comment: I'm assuming you only want one promo to show at a time. I'm unsure what you mean by "at the same time." Do you have any asynchronous stuff in your firePromo methods? If everything stays on the main thread, then I don't think you should encounter anything happening at the same time.

Comment: Nothing async, all on main thread. by "at the same time" - i just mean there's a chance both firePromo methods may evaluate at the same time. Thus the app would have to present two VC's at once. I want to avoid 'Warning: Attempt to present <_> on <_> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!' in production. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, the only solution you could use would be the else/if or early return method. Otherwise you have to get into a delegate-based solution or some alternate solution that is far beyond the scope of this answer.